# Op-Amp as Integrator

Tags: operational-amplifier

What is the application of Op-amp as Integrator? I know that the output is integral of the differential input but how does it practically work? How can it be used to condition signals?

Comment: So, first of all, you're asking three different questions in one. I'd recommend you ask one only. to answer them: 1.) application: Integrating signals. 2.) how does it practically work: Google or youtube that; nearly everyone who does Opamp tutorials covers that. Short version is: Physics leads to the voltage across a capacitor being proportional to the charge that has flown into it. 3) unclear question. It integrates signals. If that is what you need, you use it.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I have gone through the tutorials and its theoretically clear for me. I want application level understanding.For example to drive a laser diode, an op-amp is configured as an integrator with positive input as DAC set voltage and negative input is Laser voltage. Why integrator why cant I go for difference amplifier?

Comment: Why not ask that specifically? It's easier to answer specific questions than answering a bunch of broad ones where it's not clear what you've already understood and what needs to be explained! From your question alone, I'd assume you haven't understood what an Opamp does and why the output is the integral of the input.

Comment: You have an answer to your very broad question and please respect the answerer in that if you change your question you are doing him a disservice. If you need to ask about the laser control then raise this as a new question. Remember folk do this for free.

Comment: I am sorry if your feelings are hurt, but I did not change my question, I made it more specific.

Comment: @Manisha Please see: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask The question as it stands is too broad, books could be written on the application of integrators. Control, analog sensing, analog filtering to name a few are applications. Narrow your question down, we are limited on the size of our answers.

Answer (score 2):

Integrating circuits are used in **harmonic oscillators, active filters**, **control loops** (as Pi or PID controllers) and for mathematical operations (**average value**). In all applications, it is primarily the (nearly constant) **phase shift of 90 deg** between input and output which is expoloited.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It would be great help if you can explain one circuit where it is being used in control loop.

Comment: I am afraid, it is not possible to EXPLAIN the different purposes and effects of Pi and/or PID blocks within control loops. The purpose of such controillers is to shape the loop gain with respect to stabiliy requirements (ensuring of stabiliy margins) and step response specifications (static errors, final value theorem).